# Angular 4 http get with parameters - difference between search and params

Tags: angular

In Angular 4's HTTP package ('@angular/http'), a URLSearchParams object can be passed in the get request. When assigning the parameters object in the request method, what is the difference between using **search** and **params** as the attribute to pass the value into?

For example, what is the difference between the following two pieces of code:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('param1', 'xyz');
this.http.get('url', { search: params });
```

and

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('param1', 'xyz');
this.http.get('url', { params: params });
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Search is deprecated since 4.0 and params is preferred way of passing query params.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer, the documentation has been in constant flux and it is also very lacking in details. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

You can use HttpParams class!

Check this snippet:

```
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

private setParams(parameters): HttpParams {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    let keys = Object.keys(parameters);

    keys.forEach( (key) => {
        params = params.append(key, parameters[key].toString()); 
    });

    return params;
}
```

And in your request:

```
let params = this.setParams({});
http.get(your_url, {params: params});
```